# Changes made in HTML file are not visible on the webpage

Tags: html, css

I am creating a footer for my webpage, but whatever changes I make to the CSS and HTML file it is not being reflected or visible on the webpage.

I have been following a YouTube tutorial and have been completing every step displayed in that video, surprisingly the changes are not being reflected on my webpage eventhough I have cross checked for typos

```css
/* FOOTER */

.footer{
    background: #000000;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.footer .footer-content{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 350 px;
    display: flex;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section{
    flex: 1;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 1px solid white; 

}

.footer .footer-content h1,
.footer .footer-content h2{
    color: white;
}

.footer .footer-content .about h1 span{
    color: #05f7ff;
}

.footer .footer-content .about .contact span{
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.footer .footer-content .about .socials a{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 45px;
    height: 41px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.footer .footer-content .about .socials a:hover{
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.footer .footer-bottom{
    background: #343a40;
    color: #686868;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-content">
        <div class="footer-section about">
            <h1 class="logo-text"><span>Epic</span>Eateries</h1>
            <p>Delivering Quality lip smacking food</p>
        </div>    
        <div class="contact">
        <span><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> &nbsp; +9876543210/span>
        <span><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> &nbsp; support@google.com</span>
        </div>
        <div class="socials">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-snapchat"></i></a>
        </div>       
    </div>
        <div class="footer-section links">
            <h2>Quick Links</h2>
            <br>
            <ul>
                <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Blog</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>    
        </div>
        <div class="footer-section address">
            <p>ABC Street, XYZ  Lane, Pincode: 1234</p>
        </div>
    
    <div class="footer-bottom">
        &copy; Epic Eateries | 2020
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is how it is seen on the webpage, nothing that I wrote is visible up on the screen
[image]

Can anyone help here?

Comment: As you can see by the snippet I added, the code works. Can it be a caching issue, where you need to update using SHIFT+F5? Be sure to disable cache if you work with web.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, when you enter the developer mode, by right clicking the refresh button you can choose to hard-reload the browser page.

You should also use code-verifiers like this one: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes even if your code is right it doesn't seem to work because of the cached data.
If you want to make sure its not cache then try running it in the incognito mode.
Your code works perfectly fine for my chrome.

Also, you can try to update the version of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, you just have to clear your browser cache.

Chrome: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache

Try to learn how to use the Google Developer Console or Firefox Developer Console. You can easily inspect the div and view if the code changed or not, if not, you can clear the cache.